# Implement code coverage flush function with boiler plate code

Tags: c++

In each shared library that I build, it need to call __gcov_flush but that call should only be made when building the instrumented binaries for code review. 
In that case I'm passing

`-D__CODE_COVERAGE__`

option as a compilation flag.

And in each .so file.

```
#ifdef __CODE_COVERAGE__

void cscomm_gcov_flush()
{
    __gcov_flush();
}
#endif // __CODE_COVERAGE__
```

So I'm keeping the same source tree for both code coverage , debug and release.
Is this approach is oky, good or bad ? Can you review?

Answer (score 3):

This works (at least I assume it does), but it's not how I'd do things.

I'd put the code:

```
void cscomm_gcov_flush()
{
    __gcov_flush();
}
```

...into a file by itself (e.g., `flusher.c` or `flusher.cc`, as you prefer). Then I'd have the build tool decide whether to compile and link that into the .so files depending on whether it's building an instrumented binary or not.

```
OBJS = // file list here

ifdef __CODE_COVERAGE__
    OBJS += flusher.o
endif
```

Syntax varies with the build tool you're using of course, but I think the general idea is fairly apparent.

Looking at the code more generally, names that start with an underscore followed by another underscore or a capital letter (including `__CODE_COVERAGE__`) are all reserved for the implementation, so defining them leads to undefined behavior. If the compiler does it in response to a command line argument (or similar) that's fine, but if you're doing it yourself, you have undefined behavior.

Comment: so if I strict int __CODE_COVERAGE__ then what should I do? Can you suggest me a  new define macro name for that ?